# How to assure Data Encryption during data synchronization from first sql server database (local machine) to an other sql server database (on live ip)

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to exchange data between local SQL database and a remote sql database that resides on a LIVE IP machine.
How to make sure data transmission carry encrypted data rather than plain.

Overall in data synchronization we are performing two steps:

1. we send some data from local database to remote database
2. we get some data from remote database and update it in our local database based on some primary key.

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Encrypt the connection - not the data - using TLS (see article linked above)

Comment: @David  and ADyson      Thanks for your help